# PrimeNg TreeTable. Default selected rows

Tags: angular, primeng, treetable

Could you please help me to understand how we can select/highlight rows in the tree table by default?

TreeNode interface does not have something related to the highlight row.

Thanks

**Input: a default list of IDs of nodes that need to be selected/highlighted by default**

```
<p-treeTable [(selection)]="selectedNodes"...></p-treeTable>
```

For now, I just try to update selectedNodes (for the selection property of pTreeTable) by searching in a tree (recursively). But I don't like this because, for large datasets, it is an expensive operation).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the a value for which items you need to highlight. and access in the rowData and add some class to row element to highlight. You can check the documentation for conditional style: https://primeng.org/treetable#conditionalstyle

Comment: yes, it is good, but I also need to have those rows selected by default (with a checkbox).

Comment: the same logic you can apply and can add a checkbox column and can toggle based on rowData values. right?

Comment: I am not sure if I can toggle it manually.